# Newer answer appearing as oldest when sorting by "oldest"

Tags: discussion, bug, sorting

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31421644/3297613), I'm the first to post the answer but the *oldest* tab displays only the accepted answer at first. I don't know why?

My timestamp is 4:44:15

Blorgbeard's is 4:44:25

So shouldn't my answer appear first when sorting by oldest?

Comment: It also appears that when sorting by "active" is incorrect as well. Since Nagaraj S timestamp is 4:44:28 , so his should appear first when sorting by active , but Blorgbeard's appears first.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72274/244519) this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) .

ChrisF states:

> The accepted answer floats to the top (except when it's the OP's own answer) because it's the most important answer regardless of sort order. It floats to the top when sorting by votes even if there are other higher voted answers.

Also, your question is a dup of this [meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32224/244519) that was marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

So it doesn't appear to matter which sort order you choose for answers, the accepted answer will always appear first unless it is the questioners own answer.

Comment: I'm talking about the oldest not about the votes.

Comment: @AvinashRaj seems like it applies to any of the answer sort methods [the accepted answer is the most important answer regardless of sort mode.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72273/why-is-the-accepted-answer-first-even-if-i-sort-answers-by-active-or-newest/72274#comment174474_72274) Also, there's this meta.SE dup of your question that was marked status-bydesign http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32224/244519

Comment: But I don't know why SO create thiis or oldest tab also. For ex, if an op accepted an answer where another answer was posted just 10 secs before the accepted answer, oldest tab displays the accepted answer as first, op should think that the answer which was accepted is the one poted at very first. But it was totally wrong.

Comment: Here's another related on meta.SE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/accepted-answer-shouldnt-be-sorted-to-the-top-when-sorting-by-newest-or-oldest , so yea, just probably they think accepted answer should normally always appear first. Lots of time people forget that they are sorted by oldest or activity, thus having accepted answer first makes sure they see the supposed best answer